# Can not call the solidity smart contract function from web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, angular2

I am trying to call a method in solidity smart contract through angular app, but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.contract.methods.hello is not a function
at CertificateContractService.<anonymous> (certificate-contract.service.ts:32)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:70)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
at zone-evergreen.js:855
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
```

---

### Smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract CertificateList {

    function hello() public pure returns (string memory )  {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

### Angular service

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import {WEB3} from './WEB3';

declare let require: any;
declare let window: any;


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CertificateContractService {
  private abi: any;
  private address = '0xb0fFD3498B219ad2A62Eb98fEDE591265b3C3B67';
  private contract;
  private accounts: string[];

  constructor(@Inject(WEB3) private web3: Web3) {
    this.init().then(res => {
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }

  private async init() {
    this.abi = require('../assets/abi/CertificateList.json');
    // await this.web3.currentProvider.enable();
    this.accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts();

    this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(this.abi, this.address, {gas: 1000000, gasPrice: '10000000000000'});

    this.contract.methods.hello().send()
      .then(receipt => {
        console.log(receipt);
      }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
}
```

### Provider

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import Web3 from 'web3';

export const WEB3 = new InjectionToken<Web3>('web3', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => {
    try {
      window['ethereum'].autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
      const provider = ('ethereum' in window) ? window['ethereum'] : Web3['givenProvider'];
      return new Web3(provider);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying Mist or MetaMask!');
    }
  }
});
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: First of all, being that function `hello` is constant (`pure` in your case), you should be using `call()`, not `send()`. Second, what is the value of `this.abi`?

Comment: for the ```call()``` also giving same error. ```this.abi = require('../assets/abi/CertificateList.json');``` through this line i load the that contact abi json file

Comment: web3 version is 1.2.4

Comment: Please `console.log(this.abi)` and then paste the result here.

Comment: it contain more than 290 lines. i copy the ```CertificateList.json``` file from ```build/contract``` after ```truffle migrate```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
this.abi = require('../assets/abi/CertificateList.json')
```

To this:

```
this.abi = require('../assets/abi/CertificateList.json').abi
```

And this:

```
this.contract.methods.hello().send()
```

To this:

```
this.contract.methods.hello().call()
```